# Shuffling rendered primitives

Tags: c++, qt

This is just an experiment I'm doing, but suppose that we have three rectangles that are drawn:

```
void thisDialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev)
{
    rectangle = new QRect(40, 80, 40, 90);
    painter = new QPainter(this);
    brush = new QBrush(QColor(QColor::green);
    painter->fillRect(...);
    painter->drawRect(...);

    rectangle2 = new QRect(140, 80, 40, 90);
    // and draw

    rectangle3 = new QRect(240, 80, 40, 90);
    // and draw...
}
```

And now I want to somehow shuffle the rectangles drawn. My solution is to use std::random_shuffle. The plan is we push all the rectangles into a vector thereof:

```
vector<QRect*> vecRect;
vecRect.push_back(rectangle);
// push back other rectangles

std::random_shuffle(vecRect.begin(), vecRect.end());
```

At this point, the order of the rectangles have been shuffled. The only problem is that although they're shuffled I have to somehow reflect that in their positions and also update what's shown on-screen for the changes to be apparent. So, I propose creating a function called shuffle. I want only the x-values to change, so the y-values and the spacings of the rectangles should be left alone.

```
void shuffle()
{
    std::random_shuffle(vecRect.begin(), vecRect.end());

    for (auto it : vecRect)
    {
        // do something to the x-values in rectangle; e.g.
        it->setX(/*set something...*/);  
    }
}
```

To shuffle the rectangles along the x-axis and maintain the y-axis, and maintain the spacing in between I'd have to get a random number and add the spacing and ensure that it is within the window boundaries say 800x600.

Since I am new to Qt I have to know how Qt handles primitive positions, and so I guess that setX() from the docs would modify the x-position of the rectangle. My other enquiry is: how do we update the positions so they're reflected on what's drawn on-screen? Whenever I update positions it doesn't seem to take effect. I've tried update() but that doesn't seem to work.

Btw, I call the foresaid function through a key press, so if the key 'S' is pressed then the function is called.

TLDR; How can I shuffle x-positions in these rectangles and update their positions rendered?

Comment: Where do you set the values to the rectangle? Looks your paintEvent exactly like shown above? (memoryleak??)

Comment: I set the positions of the rectangle in the paint event. Is that legal?

Comment: Yeah of course and the shuffling itself where do you do that? Do you delte the rectangles at the end of the paintevent?

Comment: I do the shuffling in a separate function called shuffle(); The Rectangles are actually declared private under the dialog class and they are instantiated within the paintEvent function. They are not deleted within that function; this is because I want to use them within the shuffle() function.

Comment: Ok! So the problem us that each time you enter the paintevent you create a new rectangle so the shuffleing has no effect! Try to create them only once (in the constructor for example) and then in paintevent just change the position with setX()/setY()...

Comment: Sorry, just realized it wasn't setX I was supposed to call! I used one of the move functions which worked within the paint event, but that only happens within that function. I want to be able to move the rectangle outside the paint event; e.g. with a key press or another function call. How can I do that?

Comment: As i said... create the rectangles only once in your class... Use move/setX whatever outside the paintevent and draw them within